# Add a additional detail to the order. Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I added the dropdown list on the `checkout page` and I want to add the dropdown list value to the order detail. I tried to update the value to the meta data, but my code is not work.

Here is my code: (On Theme)

```
     <from>
     <select class = "drop-down-list" name = "drop-down-list"  id="drop-down-list" >
    <?php 
      $age = array(..,...,...);
      $wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);

     // Get the results
     $authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();

     // Check for results
     if (!empty($authors)) {

     // loop through each author
     foreach ($authors as $author)
     {
        // get all the user's data
        $author_info = get_userdata($author->ID);

        //Print out this <option value ='myName'>

        echo '<option value =\'' . $author_info->display_name . '\'>' 
          . $author_info->display_name . '</option>';
    }

    } else {
       echo 'No authors found';
    }

?>
</select>
</from>
```

And here is my plugin:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta_lmc' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta_lmc_ao($post_id) {
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    $order = new WC_Order($post_id);

    //to escape # from order id
    echo 'test this function';
    //$order_id = trim(str_replace('#', '', $order->get_order_number()));
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['drop-down-list'] ) ) {
       update_post_meta( $order_id, 'drop-down-list', sanitize_text_field(     $_POST['drop-down-list'] ) );

    }
}
 do_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed');
```

I used these code, but the data didn't update. I try put all the code on the same file, but it still doesn't work. How can I do this?

---

Here is the `<select>`
[image]

Test the function: 
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Could you make a screenshot of this dropdown in your checkout page (Where is it located?). Questions:  How you set it this drop down in your the checkout page (the complete code))?… thanks

Comment: I override the chackout page. It put in `\themes\twentyfourteen\woocommerce\checkout\form-checkout.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your plugin's code a little bit. Try this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta_lmc', 10, 2 );
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta_lmc_ao($post_id, $posted) {
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );

    //to escape # from order id

    //$order_id = trim(str_replace('#', '', $order->get_order_number()));
    if ( ! empty( $posted['drop-down-list'] ) ) {
       update_post_meta( $order->id, 'drop-down-list', sanitize_text_field( $posted['drop-down-list'] ) );

    }
}
```

One more thing, you've used `<from>...</from>` instead of `<form>...</form>`. If your drop down box is appearing in checkout form then there is no need for `<form>` tag.

Comment: tried to echo the $post_id, it return null. Also, I tried echo `$post->ID`, but it always return '6'. Actually, it is not the correct post_id.

Comment: @Capslock10 `$post_id` will be `null` only in those cases where there is some issue with order creation. Please check whether order is creating or not. If not, are you getting any errors in **Apache Error Log** or `debug.log`. Another point is that, I don't think there is any use of `global $woocommerce, $post;`. You can remove this line. Also `$post->ID` will not be helpful.

Comment: Ok.. I think the function will not be ran when I clicked the button. Because when I add a `echo '6';` it will display the text on the checkout page. Also, I need to add a `do_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed')` to trigger the function. If I don't use it, it will not do anything.

Comment: @Capslock10 I don't think you should explicitly call `do_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed')` because WooCommerce will do it after clicking **Place Order** button. Even if it is necessary for you to call `do_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed')` you should pass 2 more arguments. 1st argument should be order id & 2nd argument should be submitted form post value. WooCommerce calls it like this: `do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', $order_id, $posted );`. Remember calling action of other plugin is not recommended until you know what you are doing.

Comment: THX A LOT, I find some hint to fix ir.